# android - onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I'm calling Activity `AddRecordActivity` from Activity `ViewRecordsActivity`. Both extend `AppCompatActivity`.

I call `AddRecordActivity` as,

```
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In `AddRecordActivity` I call following code after adding the record:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddRecordActivity.this, ViewRecordsActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_OPERATION_SUCCESS_TEXT, "Record added");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And in `ViewRecordsActivity`,

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.MY_REQUEST_CODE: {
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_OPERATION_SUCCESS_TEXT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the event `onActivityResult` is not getting triggered?

Comment: please take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/10407159/2101822

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is because you are restarting it with `startActivity(intent);`. Get rid of it. Call `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);` and `finish();` only

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

&

`startActivity(intent)`

The later causes the activity to instantiate again considering it is on standard launch mode (if CLEAR_TOP flag isn't used. Otherwise the intent is delivered in onNewIntent()). Therefore, the new instance of the activity will never know you called `startActivityForResult()` from another instance of this activity. All you need to do is, quit the current activity by calling `finish()` and `setResult()` before finish() to achieve the desire result.

Comment: *The later causes the activity to instantiate again* - the CLEAR_TOP flag prevents the reinstantiation I believe

Comment: CLEAR_TOP clears all the activities in the stack above the activity that is being launched & delivers the intent again in onNewIntent() - Yes I totally missed that @TimCastelijns Thanks for pointing that out :)